# Playing videos one after the other using Pygame

Tags: python, video, pygame

I have written some Python code in an attempt to show one video after the other where I want to in Pygame:

```
import pygame
import time

def playvid(vidfile, runtime, FPS):
    print("playing" + vidfile)
    playmovie = pygame.movie.Movie(vidfile)
    movie_screen = pygame.Surface(playmovie.get_size()).convert()
    playmovie.set_display(movie_screen)
    playmovie.play()
    thentime = time.time()
    playing = True

    while playing:
        screen.blit(movie_screen,(0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)
        nowtime = time.time()
        #Play the video for 5s
        if nowtime - thentime > runtime + 1: playing = False
    print("done this one")

#FPS = 29.97
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
run = True
while run:
    playvid('snowdone.mpg', 10, 29.97)
    playvid('snowdone1.mpg', 10, 29.97)
    run = False

pygame.quit()
```

Playing the first video is fine, however, playing the second gives the warning:

"Runtime Error!

Program: C:\Python27\pythonw.exe

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."

Both videos play fine on their own so this is not an mpg problem.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the specific reason as to why the change I am suggesting works, but apparently it works.

Using your code as is, my first movie would not run for more than 4-5 seconds no matter what (it always stopped at roughly the same point) and then the pygame window would crash.

Adding a simple piece of `pygame.event.get` code in the `while playing` loop, however, fixed everything

```
while playing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pass
    screen.blit(movie_screen,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    nowtime = time.time()
    #Play the video for 5s
    if nowtime - thentime > runtime + 1: playing = False
```

It seems strange that even doing nothing in the loop for events runs the code without an issue.